# No return after executing passwd command using ssh in script

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, while-loop

I have one script which reads hosts IP from /etc/hosts file, do ssh and update the passwords there for the given user. However, the script is closed after setting password for the first host and not able to set password for rest of the hosts. Please find below files-

`/etc/hosts` file-

> 172.x.x.x  host1
>     172.x.x.x  host2
>     172.x.x.x  host3

Script I am using is as-

```
key=$1  
user=$2  
password=$3  
filename='/etc/hosts'  
while IFS= read -r line; do 
   IFS=' ' read -r -a array <<< $line
   ssh -i $key centos@${array[0]} "echo "$password" | sudo passwd $user --stdin"  
done <$filename
```

Script is simple. but it is getting closed after setting password for `host1` from file. Does anyone has any idea, what I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default ssh reads from stdin which is your input file.ssh consumes the     rest of the file and your while loop terminates.So try using

```
       ssh -n
```

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that [`ssh` is swallowing all of the standard input](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/089). The way to avoid that in general is to use a different file descriptor for your input, for example:

```
while IFS= read -u 9 -r line
do
    […]
done 9< "$filename"
```

However, this approach to changing authentication is really quite insecure, and I would strongly recommend moving to using public keys instead.

Answer (score 0):

Using awk would help overcome any issues:

```
awk -v key=$1 -v usa=$2 -v pass=$3 '{system("ssh -i "key" centos@"$1" \"echo "pass" | sudo passwd "usa" --stdin\"")}' $filename
```

Assign you passed parameters as awk variables with -v and then use these to construct the ssh command to be executed with awk's system function

Comment: you have kept filename at the end. What significance it has?

Comment: Apologies, should be $filename

Comment: Apologies, I made a mistake setting up the pass variable. Try it now. Make sure that this is set up in a script with the filename variables set to /etc/hosts and 3 parameters passed for the key, username and password